# Is Adaptive payment supported in Braintree v.zero iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, payment, braintree

I am currently working on one shopping cart application in which the payment flow works like this. When the customer pays, some portion of the amount (say 5%) will be transferred to the main owner account while the rest of amount will be transferred to the vendors account. So its an adaptive payment type of payment I guess.

After doing lots of R&D, I got an idea that I can accomplish it using the MLP library. But my client is asking for using Braintree v.zero iOS sdk. And I didn't find how we can integrate the adaptive payment with this sdk.

So, what I want to know is, Braintree v.zero iOS sdk supports adaptive payments? If yes then how? Any link?

Answer (score 4):

No, Adaptive Payments is not supported in the Braintree SDK. The Braintree SDK is a separate product distinct from any single PayPal product, although it will probably evolve similarly to PayPal's newest REST-based products.

PayPal's MPL product was a contemporary of and closely affiliated with Adaptive Payments but both products have since been superceded. Unfortunately, not all features of the earlier products are present in the newer products.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for Braintree's "market place" solution. Here's the link: https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/marketplace

Let me know if this makes sense (or not).

Answer (score 4):

I work at Braintree. Both Gautam and geewiz's answers are correct.

If you are looking for something similar to PayPal's adaptive payments with all available features, that is not something you can do with the Braintree SDK.

However, if you are looking for a system where you can facilitate transactions between two parties and charge a percentage for facilitating, then yes the [Braintree Marketplace](https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/marketplace). would meet the needs you have laid out here.  I encourage you to look at our docs to confirm that.

If you have some more detailed questions, please reach out to support@getbraintree.com and they will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I am looking into the Braintree Marketplace.

Comment: @dewyze Does Braintree market place support PayPal?

Comment: @ichathan Currently Marketplace does not support Paypal. Braintree Marketplace works through our relationship with banking partners. PayPal's Marketplace solution "Payouts" is built through a different system with their banking partners. We are revisiting the possibility of rolling PayPal into Marketplace but it is not available at this time.